# php is not working with apache after upgrading from 5.3.3 to 5.6

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos6, httpd, httpd.conf

I have a vps with bigrock which had php version 5.3.3 installed. I have recently upgraded php to version 5.6 because some php functions were not working. 
Now after removing old php and installing version 5.6 i can use php from terminal but files on my website are not being executed instead files are being downloaded with all php source code.

I think that apache is not using newly installed php. To solve this i added this line in my httpd.conf file :

```
LoadModule php5_module "/usr/bin/php"
```

This php path i got by `which php` command.
When i added this line and restarted apache it gave me a warning

```
[warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
```

I think that i need to tell apache correctly about newly installed php.

Comment: Look in the other '.conf' files - perhaps 'php.conf' You're being told that it has already been configured elsewhere.

Comment: Does your configuration have a `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` or 'AddType application/x-httpd-php .php'? Apache is not sending the scripts to php to be parsed when the browser downloads the code. Module already loaded warning means `LoadModule` was defined more than once.

Comment: I have added `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in httpd.conf. But i think that `LoadModule` is trying to load old version of php and i don't know in which configuration file. @Gmck

Comment: Are you on a cpanel/WHM server?. Cpanel/WHM servers have php module already in their templates. That might be the reason.

Comment: No , not cpanel/WHM but i am using Parellels/plesk panel. @serverliving.com

Answer (score 0):

Seing this:

`LoadModule php5_module "/usr/bin/php"`

I dont think that /usr/bin/php is the php module, it's the interpreter. Search for libphp5 or such, find /usr/lib | grep php or even better, list your php package's files and check for libphp, for example iwth rpm based distros:

`for i in $(rpm -qa | grep php); do rpm -ql $i | grep libphp; done`

Dont forget to check you're apache's error log too.

Comment: I have removed the `LoadModule` line. I checked the php.conf file in which `libphp5.so` is loading properly. and also there is nothing in error log file. Please suggest me something. My website is down. @fredi